# How do I change the title of the applet?

Tags: java

I am creating an applet and simply want to change the text located at the top of the applet, currently it says "Applet Viewer : Tetris". How do I change it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Tetris extends Applet {

    public void init() {

        setSize(250, 500);
        JPanel grid = new JPanel();
        grid.setSize(250,500);
        add(grid, BorderLayout. CENTER);


    }
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, no, you shouldn't try, why? Because an applet is suppose to be embedded within a webpage displayed by a browser, so you don't have access to the window that is ultimately displaying your applet. Now Applet was superseded by JApplet some 15+ years ago and with most browsers now days actively disabling pleats, you'd probably be better of using other mechanisms (like JFrame)

Comment: `((Frame)this.getParent().getParent()).setTitle("Hello World")` will do it, but MaProgrammer is right, you should not do this.

Comment: Ive been told to use an applet.

Answer (score 2):

Try if this works for you..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Tetris extends Applet {

  public void init() {

    Frame title = (Frame)this.getParent().getParent();
    title.setTitle("New Title");

    setSize(250, 500);
    JPanel grid = new JPanel();
    grid.setSize(250,500);
    add(grid, BorderLayout. CENTER);


  }

}
```